# Unhandled Promise Rejection: RangeError: Invalid Date on safari Vuejs

Tags: windows, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

not showing date calender in vuejs,
Date doesn't show UI on safari browser. where this date received a response from the service.

thus on android and windows can display the date calendar. it doesn't work on ios safari, chrome or mac. is there a best solution for this case?

not showing date calender in vuejs, Date doesn't show UI on safari browser. where this date received a response from the service. thus on android and windows can display the date calendar. it doesn't work on ios safari, chrome or mac. is there a best solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've researched on the same issue you have. I got my answer from this thread https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2130 I used the parse function in date-fns.

Instead of `new Date('2022-11-25')` I used `parse('2022-11-25', 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date())`.

Please note that 'yyyy-MM-dd' is based on the document of date-fns, I suggest you follow the examples there.